# Should the answer to Einstein & Quantum gravity be found in conditions of our local observable universe?

Tags: quantum-gravity, density

It seems like the discourse over a unified Einstein and Quantum Gravity disregards the phenomena encountered in our local observable universe, such as we find throughout the Intergalactic Medium. One example: Is the Density Difference between our solar system and space itself beyond the heliosphere (as Voyager left the solar system).

1. In the models attempting to unify Einstein and Quantum Gravity, shouldn't this be a consideration?
2. Would the attributes we find in the IGM/IPM help to unify the two?

Comment: I'm afraid the problems with quantum gravity are rather more fundamental then accounting for local inhomogeneities in average density.

Comment: I suspect that the answers we are looking for will come from fairly cheap table top experiments testing the limits of quantum theory in the macroscopic world. Just an opinion.

Comment: can you please give a link for what this IGM/IPM means?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143237/2451

Comment: Hi Artaudo Chrétien. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: IGM - Intergalactic Medium & IPM- Interplanetary Medium

Comment: @ QMechanic - I edited the old question and waited for several hours. 're-clarified the question and posted it anew. The old one should have been deleted. Is that ok?

Comment: @ John Rennie - Think that is what I am proposing. That the gravity problem can not ignore local phenomena.  The Field Equasions refer to the local parameters, but it only seems as far as classical physics would permit, as opposed to In-situ.

Comment: This question is different than the original. Will you make it active please?...